# How to Fetch NSManagedObject from Core data given its type and property

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I need to get a NSManagedObject from Core data so I can share it with cloud Kit. I fetch the result based on the entity property and type. Then I try to convert the result into NSManagedObject.

// Fetch NSManagedObject so it can be shared

```
if let  estProfile:  NSManagedObject = fetchEntity(uniqueId: self.energyProfileId!, entityType: EstEnergyProfile.self) {
        print("fetched NSManagedObject for sharing with cloud kit")
    }
```

//Fetch  NSManagedObject given specific property and its type

```
func fetchEntity (uniqueId: String, entityType: NSManagedObject.Type) -> NSManagedObject?{
    var obj: NSManagedObject? = nil
    
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = entityType.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueId == %@", uniqueId)
        let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        obj = fetchedResults.first as NSManagedObject
    }
    catch {
        print("Error fetching entity: ", entityType)
        
    }
    return obj
}
```

In the above code at the line

```
obj = fetchedResults.first as NSManagedObject
```

I get the error : 'NSFetchRequestResult?' is not convertible to 'NSManagedObject
I don't think I am doing this right. Can someone help fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the fetch function generic

```
func fetchEntity<EntityType: NSManagedObject>(_: EntityType.Type, uniqueId: String) -> EntityType? {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        let fetchRequest = EntityType.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueId == %@", uniqueId)
        let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return fetchedResults.first as? EntityType
    }
    catch {
        print("Error fetching entity: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example

```
let estProfile: NSManagedObject = fetchEntity(EstEnergyProfile.self, uniqueId: self.energyProfileId!)
```

Comment: When I call the function fetchEntity as suggested, I get error: Cannot convert value of type 'EstEnergyProfile.Type.Type' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'

Comment: `Type.Type`, this is the problem and it's caused by a copy/paste error on my part. I will update the answer. The first function argument should be declared as `_: EntityType.Type`

Comment: @vrao Did the updated solution work for you?

Comment: Actually it compiles but does not return the object. I know the object exists, since I create itand then call the fetchEntity method  with one of its parameters

Comment: Well that is a different issue isn't it? I have tested this code in one of my projects and it works as expected.

Comment: Let me check again, I may have something wrong in my save code.